# 404 error coming,while hitting a post request in postman

Tags: java

Url:http://localhost:8098/Users/

Body

```js
{
    "firstName": "sakti",
    "lastName": "behera",
    "email": "sakti.behera@gmail.com",
    "departmentId": "1"
}
```

Controller

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/Users")
public class UserController {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    
    @PostMapping("/")
    public User saveUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        return userService.saveUser(user);
        
    }
    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseTemplateVO getUserWithDepartment(@PathVariable("id")  Long userId ) {
        return userService.getUserWithDepartment(userId);
        
    }

}
```

Entity class

```java
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long userId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private Long departmentId;
    
    public Long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
    public void setUserId(Long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public Long getDepartmentId() {
        return departmentId;
    }
    public void setDepartmentId(Long departmentId) {
        this.departmentId = departmentId;
    }
    

}
```

Service:

```java
    enter code here
    @Service
    public class UserService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public User saveUser(User user) {
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }

    public ResponseTemplateVO getUserWithDepartment(Long userId) {
        ResponseTemplateVO vo = new ResponseTemplateVO();
        User user = userRepository.findByUserId(userId);
        Department department =
 restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8097/departments/"+user.getD epartmentId(),Department.class);
        vo.setUser(user);
        vo.setDepartment(department);
        return vo;
    }
```

I am hitting the postmethod but getting 404 not found
I have added my service,entity,and controller also.
As you have given suggestion to add (/save),I tried still It is not working
After hitting several time I saw something in my eclipse console that post method is not allowed .So it has anything to do with the code or postman ?

Comment: Data is inserted in database or not?

Comment: And you have to add your `Entity` and 'Service' things in your question. Because I didn't see any problem in your controller post method.

Comment: Controller looks good assuming that port was customized to 8098. It might be good to see the package structure, maybe spring is not scanning the package where the `Controller` class is placed (?), or maybe you can try your request without the last `/` just in case the matcher is not able to pick it up

Comment: I am using in-memory db h2.Upto now I have not implemented many features where I need to add.So ..

Answer (score 0):

The code you shared looks correct.

Did you remember to use a post request using the endpoint?
Here is an example:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8098/users/' \

--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \

--data-raw '{

    "firstName": "sakti",

    "lastName": "behera",

    "email": "sakti.behera@gmail.com",

    "departmentId": "1"

}'
```

Comment: I have tried but didnt work out

Answer (score 0):

The url should include your service-name as well.

```
http://localhost:8098/{service-name}/Users/
```

Comment: I dont think you should add your service-name.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check that your port number is 8098.
2. If the project path is configured, URL should be `http://localhost:8098/{project-path}/Users/`
3. Check if your `UserController` is in the springboot scan path. If not, you can use `@ComponentScan` annotation add it to the scan path.
4. You can try to change '/' to '/save'. URL is `http://localhost:8098/Users/save`
5. Please give your postman feedback.

Comment: I have tried both options like removing (/),adding (/save).adding (@componentscan).Nothing really helped